# What if I want to freeze the code containing appium in pyinstaller?

Tags: python, appium

I made main.py like this and tried to freeze it with pyinstaller.

```
import sys
import os
import appium


class Plugin:
    def pytest_sessionfinish(self):
        print("*** test run reporting finishing")

if __name__ == '__main__':

    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
        path = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
    elif __file__:
        path = os.path.dirname(__file__)

    pathstr = path
    patharr = pathstr.split('/')

    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        sys.exit(pytest.main( sys.argv[1:], plugins=[Plugin()]))

    if 'test' in patharr[-1]:
        sys.exit(pytest.main([pathstr], plugins=[Plugin()]))

    sys.exit(pytest.main([ '/'.join(patharr[0:patharr.index('Mobile') + 1]) + '/case'], plugins=[Plugin()]))
```

But no matter how I change the options, I get this error.

```
_pytest/config/__init__.py:570: in _importconftest
    ???
_pytest/pathlib.py:524: in import_path
    ???
_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:170: in exec_module
    ???
Automation/Mobile/conftest.py:4: in <module>
    from appium import webdriver
E   ImportError: cannot import name 'webdriver' from 'appium' (/Users/Denier/Automation/Mobile/dist/main/appium/__init__.pyc)
```

Is there a way to import and use the correct appium path in pyinstaller?